# Fields not appearing in custom Default New Form

Tags: column, custom-form

I created a custom layout for my SharePoint new record form, I added to content editors where I placed the html and .js file.

For some reason when I enter in the .js file the text box fields appear in the preview menu. but when I go to enter in a new record the input fields are not there... anyone know why?

Script I am using.
[image]

[image]

[image]
Now when I actually go into enter  are record, those boxes disappear... why is that happening

[image]

Comment: Matt..Please copy the code instead of using screen shots.

Comment: This is the script <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .ms-formtable
  {display:none;}
</style><script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {  $("span.hillbillyForm").each(function()
        {
            displayName = $(this).attr("data-displayName");
            elem = $(this);
  $("table.ms-formtable td").each(function(){
                if (this.innerHTML.indexOf('FieldName="'+displayName+'"') != -1){
                    $(this).contents().appendTo(elem);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: Try inspecting page using developer tools while entering new record. Do you see any errors/warnings in console?

Comment: This is the html code
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled 2</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>New Item</h1>
<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="15" >
    <tr >    <td> <b>Area:</b> <font color="red">*</font> <br/>
            <span class="hillbillyForm" data-displayName="JPPNum"></span>
 </td> <td>
            <b>Legacy AFE:</b> <font color="red">*</font> <br><span class="hillbillyForm" data-displayName="Vendor"></span> </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: none, any thoughts guys @jpollar

Answer (score 3):

SharePoint 2013 is using Client Side Rendering by default, so form controls are rendered on client side on some other internal javascript events. It is possible that jQuery.ready() handler is firing too early  while controls are not rendered yet and that could be main problem.

My suggestion would be not to use jQuery.ready, where normal jsLink with CSR template override should be used. In this scenario CSR post render `OnPostRender` event should help you.

Here is sample how it could be used https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-a52cf8a7

Comment: so the script would look like this??? <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script> <style type="text/css"> .ms-formtable {display:none;} </style><script type="text/javascript"> $(document).OnPostRender(function() { $("span.hillbillyForm").each(function() { displayName = $(this).attr("data-displayName"); elem = $(this); $("table.ms-formtable td").each(function(){ if (this.innerHTML.indexOf('FieldName="'+displayName+'"') != -1){ $(this).contents().appendTo(elem); } }); }); }); </script>

Comment: Actually, no. You should look deeper at how you should use CSR in SharePoint 2013, here is more examples https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a . I would also recommend not to use Content Editor Web Part but to use JSLink for new form web part http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2013-using-the-spfield-jslink-property-to-change-the-way-your-field-is-rendered-in-sharepoint-2013 These links should help you if you are new to CSR in SharePoint

Comment: I cant find jslink, im not sure why my original code is not working, I tried it on other SharePoint sites and it works fine, but with this site it isn't  working.

Comment: If you do not want to use CSR, you could try to turn off CSR and use server side rendering for the web part. Go to the web part settings and switch to Server side rendering. Go to the new form web part settings and choose "Server render" http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/268013

Comment: I don't see that option to turn off csr http://tinypic.com/r/291mb1j/8

Comment: You are looking at the wrong web part settings. Please, choose the default form web part settings and look there.

Comment: If your choose default new form, what web parts where are?

Comment: I have asked what web parts are already in the form. Maybe you have accidently deleted standard new form web part from the page?

Comment: please see link http://tinypic.com/r/2i95m68/8... also the script hides the new form page, so that my custom form can appear and the the spans column names can be used once.

Comment: So open settings of that web part you have hidden. There you could whitch to server rendering.

Comment: CSR render mode is currently StandardLayout, I tried switching it to CSR but still no luck... Is it possible that the script isn't hiding the original form that's why the input boxes aren't appearing on my custonnewform?

Comment: my supervisor made me a Site Collection Administration, and now I see the input boxes. Thank you ECM4D for your thoughts.